# How to select value from drop down

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a form and the drop down do not click

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Lead.Step2.Industry']")).sendKeys("Agriculture");
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO7R4.png) of the code

I used select method with Index, it did not work. 
then used Click with xpath, it worked but the value is not getting selected

The code -

Select an Industry

Agriculture

Getting "Elements are not interactable"

Comment: Please provide your code in the questions.  Along with what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Here is the code-     <select id="organization-details__industry" required="" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Industry field is required." name="Lead.Step2.Industry" class="choices__input is-hidden" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-choice="active"><option value="" selected="">
                                Select an Industry
                            </option></select>
<div class="choices__item choices__item--selectable" data-item="" data-id="2" data-value="Agriculture" aria-selected="true">
        Agriculture
      </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendKeys used for type value in textbox. If it is a drop down input, you need to use selectByVisibleText or selectByIndex. I hope it will help for you.

```
 WebElement mySelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Lead.Step2.Industry']"));
 Select mySelectd= new Select(mySelect);         
 mySelectd .selectByVisibleText("Agriculture");
```

It will select "Agriculture" option in your drop down.

If you need to select drop down by visible text, you can use following method:

```
 public static void selectByVisible(WebElement lelement,String selectValue) {
    WebElement mySelect =lelement;                  
    Select mySelectd= new Select(mySelect);         
    mySelectd .selectByVisibleText(selectValue);
 }
```

If you need to select drop down by index,

```
public static void selectByIndex (WebElement lelement,int selectValue) {
    WebElement mySelect =lelement;                  
    Select mySelectd= new Select(mySelect);         
    mySelectd .selectByIndex(selectValue);
 }
```